# Ubuntu downgrade php 5.5 to php 5.4

Tags: php, ubuntu, downgrade

Every time I `apt-get autoremove ppa-purge autoclean` everything the apt-cache policy php5 remains on php 5.5.x.

I already removed the ppa:ondrej/php5 and added ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable but I can not get to downgrade php 5.5 to php 5.4.

This is so frustrating, can somebody please help me? Im running Ubuntu 14 on a VM and what I did:

- install ubuntu
- `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5`
- `apt-get update` , `apt-get install php5`

At that point I had php 5.5 with no problem at all but because of zendguard I need to downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

this was really stupid of me. I just read that oldstable will not be supported on ubuntu 14, only 12.04.

Thanks for the efforts